# How to delete first voltage reading?

Tags: arduino-uno

### I'm trying out a new ADC, ADS1262, below is the code. I want to discard the first voltage reading.

```
*/
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ads1262.h>

#define PGA 1                     // Programmable Gain = 1
#define VREF 2.50                 // Internal reference of 2.048V
#define VFSR VREF/PGA             
#define FSR (((long int)1<<23)-1)  

ads1262 PC_ADS1262;                     // class

float volt_V=0;
float volt_mV=0;
volatile int i;
volatile char SPI_RX_Buff[10];
volatile long ads1262_rx_Data[10];
volatile static int SPI_RX_Buff_Count = 0;
volatile char *SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr;
volatile int Responsebyte = false;
volatile signed long sads1262Count = 0;
volatile signed long uads1262Count=0;
double resolution;



void setup() 
{
  // initalize the  data ready and chip select pins:
  pinMode(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN, INPUT);                  //data ready input line
  pinMode(ADS1262_CS_PIN, OUTPUT);                   //chip enable output line
  pinMode(ADS1262_START_PIN, OUTPUT);               // start 
  pinMode(ADS1262_PWDN_PIN, OUTPUT);                // Power down output   

  Serial.begin(9600);
  //initalize ADS1292 slave
  PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Init();                      // initialise ads1262
  Serial.println("ads1262 Initialised successfully....");

 }

void loop() 
{
  volatile int i,data;


 if((digitalRead(ADS1262_DRDY_PIN)) == LOW)               // monitor Data   ready(DRDY pin)
  {  
    SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr = PC_ADS1262.ads1262_Read_Data();      // read 6 bytes conversion register
    Responsebyte = true ; 
  }

  if(Responsebyte == true)
  {
    for(i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
      SPI_RX_Buff[SPI_RX_Buff_Count++] = *(SPI_RX_Buff_Ptr + i);              
    }
    Responsebyte = false;
  }

  if(SPI_RX_Buff_Count >= 5)
  {     


    ads1262_rx_Data[0]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[1];  // read 4 bytes adc count
    ads1262_rx_Data[1]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[2];
    ads1262_rx_Data[2]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[3];
    ads1262_rx_Data[3]= (unsigned char)SPI_RX_Buff[4];


     uads1262Count = (signed long) (((unsigned long)ads1262_rx_Data[0]<<24)| ((unsigned long)ads1262_rx_Data[1]<<16)|(ads1262_rx_Data[2]<<8)|      ads1262_rx_Data[3]);//get the raw 32-bit adc count out by shifting
     sads1262Count = (signed long) (uads1262Count);      // get signed value
     resolution = (double)((double)VREF/pow(2,31));       //resolution= Vref/(2^n-1) , Vref=2.5, n=no of bits
// Serial.print(resolution,15);
     volt_V      = (resolution)*(float)sads1262Count;     // voltage = resolution * adc count
     Serial.print(volt_V,8);

   }

  SPI_RX_Buff_Count = 0;

}

float mapfloat(float x, float in_min, float in_max, float out_min, float out_max)
{
  return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}
```

Comment: Why not just read the voltage reading once in **setup()**?   Right after the init. A dummy read there, and then no extra variables or logic in the **loop()** code.   Simple enough.    Or even make the 'get a reading' code into a function/subroutine.  Call it once at the end of the **setup()** function, first reading is eaten and call 'get a reading' function in **loop()** as desired.  Again, no extra variables or logic required.

Comment: @lornix: Simplest solution so far! As a matter of practice in any project using an A/D, I read it couple of times as part of its setup and again after any configuration change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the code shown in the other answer will do.

```
int read_first = 0;
```

That allocates `read_first` and sets it to zero.

```
if (read_first ) {
    volt_V      = (resolution)*(float)sads1262Count;     // voltage = resolution * adc count
    Serial.print(volt_V,8);
}
else {
   // discarded first result, now we've read the first one
   read_first = 1;
}
```

First time in, `read_first` evaluates false, so the `else` branch will be taken, and `read_first` set to 1.  Note that no reading has been taken yet, so the  “// discarded first result, now we've read the first one” comment is incorrect and irrelevant.  Second and later times in, `read_first` evaluates  true, so `volt_V` readings will be taken and printed.

To correct the problems with that code, use an approach like the following.

```
int useReading = 0;
...
volt_V = resolution*(float)sads1262Count;
if (useReading ) {
    Serial.print(volt_V,8);
    // and otherwise use the reading as desired
}
useReading = 1;
```

After this takes a first reading, it doesn't use that reading because `useReading` evaluates false.  Subsequent readings get used because `useReading` is turned on after the first reading.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to have a flag to specify whether you've read the first reading or not.  Default to zero:

```
int read_first = 0;
```

Then you can say:

```
if (read_first ) {
    volt_V      = (resolution)*(float)sads1262Count;     // voltage = resolution * adc count
    Serial.print(volt_V,8);
}
else {
   // discarded first result, now we've read the first one
   read_first = 1;
}
```